# Why is the password entered in the shard directories created in the distributed engine table directory?

Tags: clickhouse

I have set up 3 shards including local shards on the cluster as shown below.

```
<log>
    <secret>users</secret>
    <shard>
         <replica>
             <host>127.0.0.1</host>
             <port>9000</port>
         </replica>
    </shard>
    <shard>
         <replica>
             <host>remote1</host>
             <port>9000</port>
         </replica>
    </shard>
    <shard>
         <replica>
             <host>remote2</host>
             <port>9000</port>
         </replica>
    </shard>
</log>
```

And I created a distributed engine table including the shrding key.

When INSERT Query is executed on a distributed table,
a directory of shards containing passwords is created in the 'distributed table directory' in the 'ClickHouse data directory'.

For example, if the ClickHouse data directory is

`/etc/clickhouse-server/data/`

and a distributed table named `log_total` is created in the local db.

When I execute `INSERT INTO local.log_total .....` query.

In this path `(/etc/clickhouse-server/data/local/log_total/)`
three directories are created as shown below.

```
default:password@127%2E0%2E0%2E1:9000#dbname
default:password@remote1:9000#dbname
default:password@remote2:9000#dbname
```

I wish this directories didn't contain passwords.

I thought using the secret tag would solve it, but it wasn't.

Is there any good way?

Please share your experience.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting for this

```
 --use_compact_format_in_distributed_parts_names arg  
                              Changes format of directories names for distributed table insert parts.
```

and it's enabled by default

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    value
FROM system.settings
WHERE name = 'use_compact_format_in_distributed_parts_names'

┌─name──────────────────────────────────────────┬─value─┐
│ use_compact_format_in_distributed_parts_names │ 1     │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

If use_compact_format_in_distributed_parts_names=1 then folder name became `shard_1_replica_1` without username/password.

What CH version do you use?

Comment: thank you for answer.
I used 20.11.7.16 version.
In my CH as 'use_compact_format_in_distributed_parts_names ' is diabled by default.
And I executed the 'SET use_compact_format_in_distributed_parts_names=1' query.
but directory name is same

Comment: thank you. It works fine.
What did not work well was INSERT using python's clickhouse-driver.
Have a nice day.